# To know whether insert shortcode in custom meta box

Tags: shortcode

I build custom meta box that get text and i need to know if user insert shortcode inside and convert the shortcode to his code.

for example: inside textarea user insert: Hello Word [contact-form-7 id="63" title="Contact form 1"]
the textarea can get strings and html and shortcodes...
the result will be: Hello Word and his form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcode won't automatically execute. I order to achieve your result you need to apply a filter. When you `echo` the value of your metabox in frontend do it like this:

`echo apply_filters( 'the_content', YOUR_METABOX_VALUE_HERE );`

this way contact form shortcode will execute and form will show.

Comment: Hello 
'the_content' its not refers to post content? how its work with my metabox?

Comment: it's a filter. Not the function that refers post content. If you use this filter like I showed it will make sure shortcode inside your metabox will render properly

Comment: OK thanks i will try it...